# React.js Login with Firebase --> TypeError: setUser is not a function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, firebase-authentication

When I want to log in and enter the correct email address and password, and then click on the "Login" button, the error message appears: setUser is not a function. But after the error message, the user is still logged in. How can I fix this????

App.js

```
function App() {
  const [user, setUser] = useState(null);
  const [authState, setAuthState] = useState(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    const unsubscribe = onAuthStateChanged(auth, async (authenticatedUser) => {
      if (authenticatedUser) {
        setUser(authenticatedUser.email);
        setAuthState("dashboard");
      } else {
        setUser(null);
        setAuthState(null);
      }
    });

    return unsubscribe;
  }, [user]);

  if (authState === null)
    return (
      <>
        <Navbar />
        <div className="container">
          <Routes>
            <Route path="/" element={<Home />} />
            <Route path="/AdminLogin" element={<AdminLogin />} />
            <Route path="/SpielerLogin" element={<SpielerLogin />} />
            <Route path="/Spiel" element={<Spiel />} />
            <Route path="/HighscoreListe" element={<HighscoreListe />} />
          </Routes>
        </div>
      </>
    );
  if (user)
    return (
      <>
        <Dashboard user={user} setAuthState={setAuthState} setUser={setUser} />
      </>
    );
}

export default App;
```

Dashboard.js:

```
import React from "react";
import { signOut } from "firebase/auth";
import { auth } from "../firebase";
import Navbar from "../Navbar";
import { Route, Routes } from "react-router-dom";
import { Link, useMatch, useResolvedPath } from "react-router-dom";

export default function DashBoard({ user, setUser, setAuthState }) {
  const signOutHandler = () => {
    signOut(auth)
      .then(() => {
        setUser(null);
        setAuthState("login");
      })
      .catch((err) => console.log(err));
  };
```

AdminLogin.js:

```
import React from "react";
import { signInWithEmailAndPassword } from "firebase/auth";
import { auth } from "../firebase";

export default function AdminLogin({ setUser, setAuthState }) {
  const [email, setEmail] = React.useState("");
  const [password, setPassword] = React.useState("");
  

  const handleLogin = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();

    if (email !== null && password !== null) {
      signInWithEmailAndPassword(auth, email, password)
        .then(() => {
          setUser(email);
          setAuthState("dashboard");
        })
        .catch((err) => alert(err));
    }
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <div className="flex min-h-full items-center justify-center py-12 px-4 sm:px-6 lg:px-8">
        <div className="w-full max-w-md space-y-8">
          <div>
            <h2 className="mt-6 text-center text-3xl font-bold tracking-tight text-gray-900">
              Anmelden
            </h2>
          </div>
          <form className="mt-8 space-y-6" action="#" method="POST">
            <input type="hidden" name="remember" defaultValue="true" />
            <div className="-space-y-px rounded-md shadow-sm">
              <div>
                <label htmlFor="email-address" className="sr-only">
                  Email address
                </label>
                <input
                  id="email-address"
                  name="email"
                  value={email}
                  onChange={(e) => setEmail(e.target.value)}
                  type="email"
                  autoComplete="email"
                  required
                  className="relative block w-full appearance-none mb-2 border border-gray-300 px-3 py-2 text-gray-900 placeholder-gray-500 focus:z-10 focus:border-yellow-500 focus:outline-none focus:ring-yellow-500 sm:text-sm"
                  placeholder="E-Mail"
                />
              </div>
              <div>
                <label htmlFor="password" className="sr-only">
                  Password
                </label>
                <input
                  id="password"
                  value={password}
                  onChange={(e) => setPassword(e.target.value)}
                  name="password"
                  type="password"
                  autoComplete="current-password"
                  required
                  className="relative block w-full appearance-none border border-gray-300 px-3 py-2 text-gray-900 placeholder-gray-500 focus:z-10 focus:border-yellow-500 focus:outline-none focus:ring-yellow-500 sm:text-sm"
                  placeholder="Passwort"
                />
              </div>
            </div>

            <div>
              <button
                onClick={handleLogin}
                className="group relative flex w-full justify-center rounded-md border border-transparent bg-yellow-400 hover:bg-yellow-500 py-2 px-4 text-sm font-medium focus:outline-none focus:ring-offset-2"
              >
                Anmelden
              </button>
            </div>
          </form>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

I do not know how to fix the setUser.

Comment: What do you expect to happen differently than what you're observing now?  Please edit the question to be more clear.  Note that we can't see what setUser is because it's a parameter to a function and we can't see where it's being called or what value it's being passed. Ideally there is enough information in the question that we can use to duplicate the results.

Comment: Okay, I did now. This are all the files I have.

Comment: You don't pass any props to `AdminLogin`; there's no `setUser` in that component. That said: your description of the error is unclear: **when** does the error happen? Where is the error coming from? Etc..